# Flutter Provider- Setting Streamprovider error in home.dart

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm using a custom route to create a transition effect but I'm having some problems with a 
value using `Provider`.

Error

```
Another exception was thrown: Error: Could not find the correct Provider<List<FireFavorites>> above this Favorites Widget
```

home.dart

```
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider.value(
          value: db.streamFavorites(user.uid),
        )
      ],
      child: Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder<NavBarItem>(
          stream: _bottomNavBarBloc.itemStream,
          initialData: _bottomNavBarBloc.defaultItem,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<NavBarItem> snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.data) {
              case NavBarItem.SEARCH:
                return Search();
              case NavBarItem.BROWSE:
                return Browse();
              case NavBarItem.ICON:
                return About();
              case NavBarItem.FAVORITES:
                return Favorites();
              case NavBarItem.SETTINGS:
                return Settings();
              default:
                return null;
            }
          },
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: ConvexBottomNav(navBarHandler: _navBarHandler),
      ),
    );
  }
```

custom route class

```
class MyCustomPageRoute extends MaterialPageRoute {
  final Widget previousPage;

  MyCustomPageRoute(
      {this.previousPage, WidgetBuilder builder, RouteSettings settings})
      : super(builder: builder, settings: settings);

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget currentPage) {
    Animation<Offset> _slideAnimationPage1 =
        Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(0.0, 0.0), end: Offset(-1.0, 0.0))
            .animate(animation);
    Animation<Offset> _slideAnimationPage2 =
        Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(1.0, 0.0), end: Offset(0.0, 0.0))
            .animate(animation);
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        SlideTransition(position: _slideAnimationPage1, child: previousPage),
        SlideTransition(position: _slideAnimationPage2, child: currentPage),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

using the class like this which is in `Browse()`. I simply want to navigate to a document. But using `MyCustomPageRoute` causes the `Provider` error.

```
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MyCustomPageRoute(
      previousPage: this,
      builder: (context) => Document(
        documentID: docid,
      ),
    ),
  );
```

I would like to have the favorites `StreamProvider` in main.dart, but I don't have access to the  authenticated user's `uid` there, or I don't know how to access it after it becomes available. Below is how I have `Provider` set up in `main.dart`. I can just make a simple request in `home.dart`, get the favorites and add them to `Content()` and the access them throughout the app, but I would like to have a stream.

main.dart

```
  return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<FirebaseUser>.value(
          value: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Content>.value(
          value: Content(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: '',
        theme: ThemeData(
          fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          primaryColor: Color(0xff2398C3),
        ),
        home: WelcomePage(),
      ),
    );
```

Any idea how can this be fixed?

Comment: where you initialize the provider for FirebaseUser ?

Comment: It's initialised in `main.dart`

Comment: you can initialise in the main, and set it later when you have the uid

Comment: That sounds good. What would that look like?